# Getting `[ [Object] ]` as nested array of object response on MongoDB Aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to do an aggregation on two collections that has a linkage between them, and I need to access information in an array of objects in one of those collections.

Here are the schemas:

```
User Schema:
{
    _id: ObjectId,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    associatedEvents: [
        {
            event_id: ObjectId,
            isCreator: boolean,
            access_level: String,
        }
    ]
}

Event Schema:
{
    _id: ObjectId,
    title: String,
    associated_users: [
        {
            user_id: ObjectId
        }
    ]   
}
```

I'm attempting to get the users associated to an event for a specific user, and then get their access level information. Here's the aggregation I have:

```
const eventsJoined = await Event.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: { $in: [id, "$associatedUserIds"] },
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "associatedUserIds",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user_info",
    },
  },
  { $unwind: "$user_info" },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$user_info.associatedEvents",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      title: { $first: "$title" },
      description: { $first: "$description" },
      startDate: { $first: "$startdate" },
      userInfo: { $first: "$user_info" },
      usersAssociatedEvents: { $push: "$user_info.associatedEvents" },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      title: 1,
      description: 1,
      startDate: 1,
      userInfo: 1,
      usersAssociatedEvents: "$usersAssociatedEvents",
    },
  },
]);
```

And this is the result I'm getting:

```
[
  {
    _id: 609d5ad1ef4cdbeb32987739,
    title: 'hello',
    description: 'desc',
    startDate: null,
    usersAssociatedEvents: [ [Object] ]
  }
]
```

As you can see, the query is already aggregating the correct data. But the last thing that's tripping me up is the fact that the aggregation is `[ [Object] ]` for `usersAssociatedEvents` instead of the actual contents of the object. Any idea on why that would be?

Comment: i think its just wrapped by console any editor that you are using, you are getting correct data, just try to console only `usersAssociatedEvents[0]` it will show result.

Comment: Oh shit, you're right. If i look at the response in the client, after it's gone through the `JSON.stringify`, it's all expanded out. Thank you so much!!!

It's funny cuz that's just the normal `console.log` and the integrated VSCode terminal.